# Strange border in Microsoft Word file that doesn't go away

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I opened a pdf file in Microsoft Word (Office 2016, it automatically converts the file to .docx format) which had no page borders in it. After finishing a few edits, I further exported the word file back to pdf format. Now, on opening the new pdf file, I can see page borders at the bottom of each page, which do not go away on selecting `None` in the `Design -> Page borders` menu. I have tried many ways to get rid of the border but it just doesn't work.

Link to the word file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XRrGrbtTOmTOboGkumBpQazA5TXdpGPL/view?usp=sharing

Converted PDF file of the same file (with strange borders in it): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TnEODNVdvhbz3Ubmy4yA3y34rELQSO4T/view?usp=sharing

(Please download the Word file and open it in Microsoft Word only)

Please help me out to resolve this, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded both the DOCX and the PDF.  I opened the DOCX with Word 2016 (Office 365) newest version and Adobe Pro DC newest. There are no borders either place.

Look in Word, Options, Advanced, and ensure "Show Text Boundaries" under Show Document Content is disabled.

Follow up note: In Adobe Pro (probably also Standard), it shows you a Page Gap between pages. This is not a line, and does not print.  You may be able to reduce the appearance of this line by scrolling when reading. I do not do this as the gap is a known quantity and does not bother me.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/how-to-remove-vertical-spacing-between-pages/td-p/9661912?page=1

Also watch for and remove any excess page breaks at the end of the Word Document before making a PDF from it .

Comment: could you please re-check the last page of the word file for any borders?

Comment: There were no borders at the end of the Word file, but there were extra page breaks (that can be deleted) that might cause extra gaps in Adobe. I adjusted this fine point in my answer